# Ionic 2 (angular 2 typescript) - Cannot applying data to view

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

i'm stuck because ionic 2 .
i have a problem, i want to render card component using `*ngFor` with title of an article and other data like thumbnail ,etc.
When i'm hardcoded value in array , card shows. BUT , when i'm using REST API card doesn't rendered. Data retrieved succesfully.

Is there any like `$scope.$digest();` in angular 1 for applying changes on `$scope` for angular 2(Ionic 2)
or how to get what i want ?

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as moment from 'moment';
var itemList =[];
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})



export class HomePage  {
  

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    moment.locale('id');
    this.getNews();
  }


  getNews(){
    $.ajax({
      url: secret_api_url ,
      dataType:"jsonp",
      method:"get",
      success:(data =>{
        var post = data.posts;
        post.forEach(function(p){
          p.date = moment(p.date).format('lll');
          itemList.push(p);
        });
        // itemList = post;

      }),
      error:(err =>{
        console.log("Error",err);
      })
    });
  }










}
```

```html
    <ion-card padding *ngFor="let item of itemList;">

    <ion-card-content>
      <label style="color:white;">
        {{i}}
        <label class="timestamp">{{ item.date }}</label>
      </label><br>
      <small>
            <i>
            {{ item.short_desc }}
            </i>
      </small>
      <ion-card-title>
        {{item.title}}
      </ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-content>
    <img src="{{item.img_url}}"/>
  </ion-card>
```

Comment: Post some codes

Comment: Please give your question a title which describes it.

Comment: Done,some codes is posted and title described . 

sorry for my bad , because i'm too stuck there

Answer (score 1):

Ensure data from your rest API is correctly converted into instances of a class:

```
export class Article{
    constructor(public id: string, public title: string) {}
}

// Your component:

this.articles: Array<Articles> = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.articleService.getArticles()
        .subscribe(articles => { 
                this.articles = articles.map(item => new Article(item.id, item.title);
            }); 
        });      
}
```